How can i create a same pv and pvc for all the pods running in a same namespace running in a Google kubernetes cluster?
I am trying to create a single Persistent Volume (PV) and Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) that can be accessed by all the pods running in the same namespace on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). I attempted to use an NFS server, but when I deployed a StatefulSet, my pods did not run. Here is the configuration I used:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /path/to/nfs
    server: nfs-server.example.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeName: nfs-pv
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: example-statefulset
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  serviceName: "example-service"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example
        image: example/image
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mnt/nfs"
          name: nfs-storage
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: nfs-storage
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
      storageClassName: ""
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi

However, my pods are not starting. What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly set up a PV and PVC that can be accessed by all pods in the same namespace?

Trying to share files between containers is often an anti-pattern.  How will your containers work if multiple containers try to update the same file at the same time?  From different nodes?  If there's a network hiccup reaching the NFS server?

In your specific setup, the StatefulSet volumeClaimTemplates: is creating a new PVC for each replica.  Specifying volumeName: explicitly in that to bind to the same PersistentVolume might work (and then delete the manual PersistentVolumeClaim).  You also might skip the PV(C) setup for this particular path and just directly create an nfs: volume in the Pod spec.
